# Define comb function in terms of exponential function

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, sampling

I have one signal with $N$ samples and I want to downsample it by factor of $M$. Essentially my downsampler is comb function which takes every M$^{th}$ sample while others are set to zero, i.e.,

$$
\check{Y}_k=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\sum_{m=0}^{\frac{N}{M}-1}x[n]\delta(n-mM)e^{-j\frac{2\pi nk}{N}}\tag{1}
$$
where $x[n]$ is original signal, $\check{Y}_k$ is downsampled signal, and $n$ are time samples .

- How is comb function $\delta(n-mM)$ define in terms of exponential function ? i.e.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\sum_{m=0}^{\frac{N}{M}-1}\delta(n-mM)=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\sum_{m=0}^{\frac{N}{M}-1}e^{??}$$

- Also what is the definition of comb function in frequency domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The frequency domain representation of the discrete time downsampling operation (i.e.  $X_M(e^{j\omega})$ , the $DTFT\{x[Mn]\}$, in terms of $X(e^{j\omega})$, the $DTFT\{x[n]\}$ ) can be most easily observed by the following approach. We will begin from the end, $x[Mn]$ and proceed to its pre-compressed form by first deriving the frequency domain relation between the compressed signal $x[Mn]$ and its expanded form (pre-compressed) $x_s[n]$ and then we shall show the spectral relation between an input signal and its sampled form $x_s[n]$ (which is also the expanded signal at the input of the compressor)

First consider a periodic **pulse train** ,  $p_M[n] \triangleq \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}{ \delta[n-kM]}$ whose period is $M$ and defined as :

$$p_M[n]=
\begin{cases}
1 ~~~~, ~~~ \text{n = 0, M, 2M, ..., kM , ...} \\
0 ~~~~, ~~~ \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases} \tag{1}$$

Then the signal $x[n]$  will be first multiplied by this perodic pulse train $p_M[n]$, to produce $x_s[n]$ which will be selecting the required samples as follows:

$$x_s[n]=x[n]\cdot p_M[n] =
\begin{cases}
x[n] ~~~~, ~~~ \text{n = 0, M, 2M, ..., kM , ...} \\
0 ~~~~, ~~~ \text{otherwise} \tag{2}\\
\end{cases}$$

Now, we shall take every $M^{th}$ sample of $x_s[n]$ and discard the rest, which is called as the **compression** operation as graphically represented by:

$$ x_s[n] \longrightarrow \boxed{\downarrow M} \longrightarrow x_s[Mn]=x[Mn]=x_M[n] \tag{3}$$

Note that eventhough the conversion between $x[n]$ and $x[Mn]$ is not invertable, the conversion between $x_s[n]$ and $x_s[Mn]$ is so, as should be clear:

$$ x_s[Mn]=x_{sM}[n] \longrightarrow \boxed{\uparrow M} \longrightarrow x_s[n] \tag{4}$$

i.e. the inverse is the **expander** operator and we shall exploit it for **easily** showing the spectral relation between $x_s[n]$ and $x_M[n]$ as it can be shown that:

$$X_{s}(e^{j\omega}) = X_{sM}(e^{j\omega M}) \Longrightarrow  X_{sM}(e^{j\omega}) = X_{s}(e^{j\omega/ M}) \tag{5}$$

Based on this we can argue that (noting the equation (3)), $$ \boxed{ DTFT\{x[Mn]\} \triangleq X_M(e^{j\omega}) = X_{s}(e^{j\omega/ M}) } \tag{6}$$ where $X_{s}(e^{j\omega})$ is the DTFT of the sampled signal $x_s[n]$.

What comes next is the relation between the DTFTs of the signals $x_s[n]$ and $x[n]$ to complete the picture, which will be a straight forward observation if we consider representing the periodic impulse train by another form namelmy by its **DFS** (Discrete Fourier Series) representations (as is possible for any periodic discrete time signal with period M) :

$$ p_M[n] \triangleq \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}{ \delta[n-kM]} = \frac{1}{M}  \sum_{k=0}^{M-1}{e^{j \frac{2\pi}{M}kn} } \tag{7}$$

Then we shall express $x_s[n]$ as :
$$ x_s[n] \triangleq x[n]\cdot p_M[n] = x[n] \big( \frac{1}{M}  \sum_{k=0}^{M-1}{e^{j \frac{2\pi}{M}kn} }\big) = \frac{1}{M}  \sum_{k=0}^{M-1}{x[n]e^{j \frac{2\pi}{M}kn} } \tag{8}$$

What comes next is using the **linearity** and **modulation** properties of DTFT operator and argue that: 
$$DTFT\{x_s[n]\} = DTFT\{\frac{1}{M}  \sum_{k=0}^{M-1}{x[n]e^{j \frac{2\pi}{M}kn} } \} = \frac{1}{M}  \sum_{k=0}^{M-1}{ DTFT \{ x[n]e^{j \frac{2\pi}{M}kn} \} } = $$ $$ \boxed{X_s(e^{j\omega})=\frac{1}{M}  \sum_{k=0}^{M-1}{ X(e^{j \big(\omega -\frac{2\pi}{M}k \big)} ) } } \tag{9}$$

The final step is the mergal of the steps (6) and (9) to produce the result:
$$ \boxed{ X_M(e^{j\omega}) = X_s(e^{j\omega/M})=\frac{1}{M}  \sum_{k=0}^{M-1}{ X(e^{j \big(\frac{\omega}{M} -\frac{2\pi}{M}k \big)} ) } = \frac{1}{M}  \sum_{k=0}^{M-1}{ X(e^{j \big(\frac{\omega-2\pi k}{M} \big)} ) } } \tag{10} $$

I hope it was a clear way of expressing the spectrum of downsampled signal $x_M[n]=x[Mn]$ to that of the original signal $x[n]$

Also note that a more complete understanding of the spectral relation would only be possible if you fully explore the relation by a **graphical plot** as well, which would clearly demonstrate the resulting **frequency stretching** towards the $\omega  =\pi$ boundary, by a factor of $M$ after which a consideration of **aliasing** becomes clear...

Comment: Just one comment: shouldn't be in Eq. (7) $p_m[n]=..=\frac{1}{M}\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}e^{j\frac{2\pi nk}{M}}$?

Comment: @Cali yes you are right! It should be M, not N... let me correct.

Comment: Then I think the same editing should be done in Eq. (8). However, a nice and detailed answer. Thank you!

Comment: yeees... latex itself is tiring to catch a typo... hope you understood it. I suggest you interpret the last equation (10) carefully. By adding M copies of scaled and shifted versions of $X(e^{j\omega})$ ... In particular observe the period of the scaled verison... which is not $2\pi$ but $M2\pi$

Comment: if there is a step you feel insecure, please don't hesitate to ask it as a **new** question... ;-)

Comment: Could I ask you if you could explain a little bit more how did you come to qualities in Eq. (5). Time domain relation is quite clear but I didn't get completely spectral relations.